# Sinon Promise resolving after unit tests have completed

Tags: unit-testing, promise, sinon, chai

I would like to write some unit tests for a particular function that has promises, however, the promise resolves after the tests have completed. For example:

```
  function systemUnderTest(promise, cb) {
    return promise.then(data => {
      console.log('>>>', data);
      cb(data);
    });
  }

  it('resolves and calls the sampleFunc', () => {
    const spyCallback = spy(data => data)
    systemUnderTest(Promise.resolve(42), spyCallback);
    expect(spyCallback.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
```

I can see that my `log` statement triggers after the tests have completed, so when the assertion has ran, the `callCount` is obviously `0` since it didn't run at that time but much later.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a callBack it does not make too much sense to spy on it. But here is an example (just replace your own promise):

```
it('some test',function(done){
        const deferred = q.defer();
        deferred.resolve("Good");
        const callBack = function(data) {                
            expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
            done();
        }

        let spy = sinon.spy(callBack);
        systemUnderTest(deferred.promise,spy);        
    })
```

Now what I think should be better, is to test the result of the callback data, instead of spy on it. This way you also make sure that the function is invoked. Please observe the **done** argument.
Like this:

```
it('some test',function(done){
        const deferred = q.defer();
        deferred.resolve("Good");
        const callBack = function(data) {                
            expect(data).to.exist; //or any other assertion.
            done();
        }           

        systemUnderTest(deferred.promise,callBack);        
    })
```

Hope this help.